# Titanium developing: I want to put a view always visible from the second view and beyond. I'm using a scrollView

Tags: android, titanium, scrollview

I'm developing an app in Titanium. I've divided it in four different views to make a scrollView. I want to put another view always visible only from the second view and beyond. How can I do that?

Ther is my app.js code:

```
    (function(e){
            var principal = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor: '#fbfbfb',
            exitOnClose:true,
            navBarHidden: true 
            }),
            pantallaBienvenida = require('ui/pantallaBienvenida'),
            pantallaTitular = require('ui/pantallaTitular'),
            pantallaDependiente = require('ui/pantallaDependiente'),
            pantallaAsistenciaMedica = require('ui/pantallaAsistenciaMedica'),
            primeraPantalla = new pantallaBienvenida,
            segundaPantalla = new pantallaTitular,
            terceraPantalla = new pantallaDependiente,
            cuartaPantalla = new pantallaAsistenciaMedica,
            scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
                views:[primeraPantalla,segundaPantalla,terceraPantalla,cuartaPantalla]
            });     

        principal.add(scrollView);
        principal.open();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ScrollableView not ScrollView, they are very different.

If you want to show some additional info when user goes to second element of your ScrollableView you have to add new element to Window, set it's property visible = false.

Then create event listener and when dragend is fired make that view visible.

Some example code:

```
floatingView = require('ui/floatingview')
floatingView.visible = false;
principal.add(floatingView);

scrollView.addEventListener('dragend', function(event){
  if (this.currentPage !== 0) {
    floatingView.visible = true;
  } else {
    floatingView.visible = false;
  }
});
```